Can I set up autocomplete in VS Code for Revit API stubs without having Revit installed?
In my office, I have a PC that does not meet the minimum requirements to install Revit. I want to use it just for writing my API codes in VS Code, so I can use them later on another PC with Revit installed
here my settings in vscode

As an example, I can acces Autodesk.Revit.DB as  shown below but not the classs FilteredElementCollector


You can probably achieve what you need simply by copying the Revit API .NET assembly DLLs onto your programming machine. They are installed in the same directory as Revit.exe. They are also available in various NuGet packages; search for something like NuGet Revit API to find them.

Yes you can! I use it in a daily basis as a RevitAPI developer!
First you need to create stubs that are dummy objects. You can use these libraries to create them:

https://github.com/gtalarico/ironpython-stubs
https://github.com/BIMOpenGroup/RevitAPIStubs

After creating them you have to add their path to the VSCode workspace settings.json, check - how to open VS Code settings.json.
 {       
   ...
   "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}\\etc\\revit-api-stubs\\common",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\etc\\revit-api-stubs\\revit\\2022"
   ]
   ...
}

After adding the above it will show up on autocomplete.
